Is it possible to install different versions according to dev \ production in package.json
We have a public react-native package with some native components inside a sub directory in the same repo /lib, these native components are also being published.
We need to do some refactoring (internal reasons) and I wonder if it's possible to use a different version in our devDependencies and dependencies?  Something like this:
* From what I've tested this gives me the public version locally as well.
dependencies": {
  "native-lib": "^1.0.0"
},
devDependencies": {
  "native-lib": "file:./lib"
},


So our users will get the public version while we can work with the local version while developing?

I do not think it is. Both packages would land in the same folder in node_modules. That should lead to conflict.
But you could perhaps try to install your development version under (slightly) different name?
And then, even if you avoid conflict on a package-manager level, you must reference your dev version differently in your application.

The example I provided does not work - it only installs the version in the dependencies (and it was supposed to be an example, not a solution).
Not sure that installing in a different name is possible, and it'll install the version in dependencies, which will cause issues.

Maybe I just do not get it. I understand you can manually cut and paste from dependencies to devDependencies (or the other way), and that is just up to you, leads to no change in node_modules. But the problem is the folder inside node_modules, where the package(s) reside. That conflict you could avoid by using different name for one of the packages. But I actually do not understand the use case well. If you mean to install one in dev, one in prod, then https://stackoverflow.com/a/79199833/14939790

A common approach is to use scripts in your package.json file to install different versions of packages depending on the environment. You can create scripts that install separate dependencies for development and production.
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A sample project to demonstrate package.json scripts",
  "scripts": {
    "install:dev": "npm install --only=development",
    "install:prod": "npm install --only=production",
    "install": "npm install",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "dev": "webpack serve --mode development",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
    "lint": "eslint src/**/*.js",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "react": "^18.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.0.0",
    "jest": "^28.0.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=12.0.0"
  }
}

Install Scripts:
"install:dev": Installs only the development dependencies (such as webpack, eslint, etc.). Use this when you're in a development environment.
"install:prod": Installs only the production dependencies (like express and react), ignoring development dependencies.
"install": The default installation command that installs both production and development dependencies.
uild and Development Scripts:
"build": A script to build your project for production using webpack in production mode. This would typically include bundling your JavaScript, optimizing assets, etc.
"dev": Runs the development server using webpack in development mode. This is useful for local development and includes features like hot module reloading.
Start Script:
"start": Runs the application in a production environment by setting the NODE_ENV=production environment variable and then starting the application with node server.js. This would typically be the command you'd run in a production environment after deployment.
Linting and Testing:
"lint": Runs eslint on all JavaScript files in the src directory. You would use this to ensure your code adheres to your linting rules.
"test": Runs your tests using Jest. This is useful for running unit tests and other automated tests in your project.
Install Dependencies for Development:
bash
npm run install:dev

This installs only the development dependencies.
Install Dependencies for Production:
bash
npm run install:prod

Example Flow
To set up a project for development, you would typically do something like this:
Clone or create your project.
Run npm run install:dev to install all development dependencies.
Run npm run dev to start the local development server and begin working on your code.
When you're ready to deploy to production, run npm run build to create the production build and then run npm start to launch your app in a production environment.

Is this done in preinstall?

No, you don't need a preinstall script for this use case. The configuration you have in package.json with "file:./lib" in devDependencies will work automatically when you run npm install or yarn install.

You've written that "A common approach is to use scripts in your package.json", can you please provide an example?

Thank you very much for your answer (I did not know about these), however (1) from what I've read --only=dev is deprecated (2) we use yarn which does not seem to support this option.
